# Polygon in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, polygon

I want to draw polygon as per given in [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQeRl.png)! Is it possible to do so ? One more thing about polygon, I want to create it as UIView. Just like as we create rectangle and square. Because I need to use "tag" property. Is it possible to create polygon in such a way ?

I have gone through another idea that I should create three views and attach with eachother (given in [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQeRl.png)).

You can consider some view frames as per example..

**View 1) CGRectMake ( 0,0,50,50);**

**View 2) CGRectMake ( 50,0,50,50);**

**View 3) CGRectMake ( 50,50,50,50);**

I can create three views but how to concatenate these views and make one view ( **Our Polygon** )?

Can you give me solution or any advice to implement such problem ?

Comment: One approach would be to create the largest rect first and add subviews ontop of it, not sure if works though.
`[view2 addSubview:view1]`
`[view3 addSubview:view2]`

Comment: @Da_smokes If you mean to create one view with CGRectMake (0,0,100,100) and add there views as subviews, it won't be useful because I can't use frame CGRectMake (0,50,50,50); It would be useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire shape of the UIView will have to be square. You can't create a UIView that isn't square/rectangular.

You can draw it using UIBezierPath...

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
... and so on.
```

Then in drawRect you can...

```
[path stroke];
```